# How do I include/add multiple calculations using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

Pre-warning, I am new to JavaScript but I can understand calculations being made when they are already written, its writing my own that is the issue. I am trying to create an online tax calculator for our website. I have found a basis to work from but I need to update it so the calculations are correct.

**THE OBJECTIVE:**
User enters in their Gross Income and clicks on a button "Calculate". Results should show Tax Payable, Medicare Levy and finally the Net Income. Net = Gross-Tax-Medicare.

**WHERE I AM AT:**
I have found some code to work from that provided me with some tax calculations which I have updated to the correct values. However, the Medicare value (1.5%) that is currently applied to all tax brackets is incorrect, there are actually 3 different levels for this as well.

***I am not sure how to merge the two Calculations together and then deduct these from the Gross Income to give a Net Result? I havent added anything to make the final calculation, at this stage, I am trying to work out how to do multiple functions in one script.***

I am trying to gradually build this out as I go by doing one calculation at a time but stumped as soon as I tried it. I have created a test page at http://www.faa.net.au/test/.

I would really appreciate any help on this. I am waiting on a JavaScript guide to actually make some time and learn JavaScript properly.

The additional Medicare calculation I am trying to add is as follows:

```
// Calculation below needs to replace Medicare above
if (income>0 && income<=19404) {
    medicare = (income*0)/100;
}
else if (income>19404 && income<=22828) {
    medicare = (income*10)/100;
}
else if (income>22828) {
    medicare = (income*1.5)/100;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste and test here what you have done so far? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: You should post a minimal example here, not elsewhere.

Comment: Shouldn't that middle medicare amount be `(income*1)/100`?

Comment: I have tried pasting current code to jsfiddle but it doesnt work. Shall I paste here my current JavaScript?

Comment: In relation to the values, they are correct as they are, medicare thresholds are 0%, 10% and 1.5% respectively. Don't ask me why, that is the good old Australian Tax System for you! lol

Comment: I know it's got nothing to do with your technical JS question, but can you give a link to details about the Medicare levy thresholds? Just to satisfy my own curiosity as an Australian, because according to [the numbers the ATO provides](http://www.ato.gov.au/individuals/content.aspx?menuid=0&doc=/content/00250854.htm&page=3) people with income between those two numbers pay a _reduced_ levy, not seven times as much as higher income earners...

Comment: @nnnnnn - fill this out with the ranges I specified and you can see the calculations. I cant find the actual figures in a table on the website without scouring through all of the pages but I work at a Financial Advisers and they have a booklet here from the ATO outlining the thresholds for Tax & Medicare.

Comment: It's only the portion of the income over the lower threshold that gets multiplied by 10%, not the whole income, as demonstrated [by the ATO's online calculator](http://calculators.ato.gov.au/scripts/axos/axos.asp?CONTEXT=&KBS=Medicare12.xr4&go=ok)...

Comment: I have re-posted the question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598162/tax-calculations-using-javascript] so hopefully this is clearer, if it is not, please let me know and I will delete it.

Comment: @nnnnnn - I see, well spotted. That just makes things a bit more complicated as far as I am concerned, lol.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20211/discussion-between-sampotts-and-nnnnnn)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code you need is similar to this, I believe:

```
// I am using a javascript library called jQuery.
$(function(){
    // On clicking the Calculate button
    $('#calculate').on('click', function(){
        // Get the value of user supplied income from the textbox
        var income = parseInt($('#preIncome').val().trim()),
            postIncome = 0,
            medicare = 0;
        console.log(income);
        if(income > 0){
            // Calculation below needs to replace Medicare above
            if (income>0 && income<=19404) {
                medicare = (income*0)/100;
            }
            else if (income>19404 && income<=22828) {
                medicare = (income*10)/100;
            }
            else if (income>22828) {
                medicare = (income*1.5)/100;
            }
            // Calculate the new income based on derived medicare value
            postIncome = income - medicare;
        }
        // Set the new medicare and income values to the textboxes
        $('#postIncome').val(postIncome);
        $('#medicare').val(medicare);
    });
});​
```

There is a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/YdWNA/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you just need to use two variables, one for the medicare calculation and one for the tax rate. And then when you have those, you can calculate the net income.

So in JavaScript, it might look like this:

```
var medicare;
var tax; 
var income;
// This is just your medicare calculation
if (income>0 && income<=19404) {
    medicare = (income*0)/100;
}
else if (income>19404 && income<=22828) {
    medicare = (income*10)/100;
}
else {
    medicare = (income*1.5)/100;
}
// Hypothetical Tax calculation (I don't know the real tax rates)
if (income>0 && income<=20000) {
    tax = (income*25)/100;
}
else {
    tax = (income*40)/100;
}
// and now the net income using the calculated values
var netIncome=income-tax-medicare;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the guts of your form:

```
<form name="calc">

  Gross Income: <input type="text" class="innerc resform" size="15" name="income">

  <input type="button" onclick="calculate(this)" name="result" value="Calculate"
   class="calcButton">

  Income Tax:    <input type="text" size="15" class="resform" name="tax">
  Medicare Levy: <input type="text" size="15" class="resform" name="medicare">
  Net Income:    <input type="text" size="15" class="resform" name="net">
</form>
```

If you pass `this` from the calculate button (note the changed listener and addition of a value), a function to calculate the medicare levy can be:

```
function calculate(element) {
  var form = element.form;
  var income = form.income.value;

  // 0 for income less than threshold
  var medicare = 0;

  // Add 1% of income between 19404 and 22828
  if (income > 19404 && income <= 22828) {
    medicare = (income - 19404) * 0.01;
  }

  // Add 1.5% of income over 22828
  if (income > 22828) {
    medicare += (income - 22828) * 0.015;
  }
}
```

Hopefully that will get you going.